# Play framework JPA merge does not merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

using play framework 2.2 + JPA + Hibernate here.
I have these 2 Entities, Reseller and Agent, both are extending a tipical user class (name surname email)

Reseller class here

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(UserType.RESELLER)
public class Reseller extends BackendUser {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String telephone;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    public int wallet;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reseller" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Agent> agents;


    public Reseller(String name, String surname, String email, String password, String telephone_number) {
        super(name, surname, email, password);
        this.telephone = telephone_number;
        this.admin_transactions = new LinkedList<>();
        this.reseller_transactions = new LinkedList<>();
        this.agents = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reseller", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<AdminResellerTransaction> admin_transactions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reseller", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<ResellerClientTransaction> reseller_transactions;

    public static Optional<Reseller> get(final String email){
        try{
            return Optional.of((Reseller) JPA.em().createQuery("select c from Reseller c where c.email = ?1").setParameter(1 , email).getSingleResult());
        }catch (NoResultException e){
            return Optional.absent();
        }
    }

    public static List<Reseller> getAll(){
        return JPA.em().createQuery("select a from Reseller a").getResultList();
    }


}
```

Agent class here:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(UserType.AGENT)
public class Agent extends BackendUser {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;


    @Constraints.Required
    public String telephone;

    public Agent(String name, String surname, String email, String password, String telephone, Reseller reseller) {
        super(name, surname, email, password);
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.reseller = reseller;
        this.users = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="reseller_id")
    public Reseller reseller;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<SimpleUser> users;

    public static List<Agent> getAll(){
        return JPA.em().createQuery("select a from Agent a").getResultList();
    }

    public static Optional<Agent> get(final String email){
        try{
            return Optional.of((Agent) JPA.em().createQuery("select c from Agent c where c.email = ?1")
                    .setParameter(1 , email).getSingleResult());
        }catch (NoResultException e){
            return Optional.absent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the Play Form class to implement a CRUD over the entities, here i'm trying to update an existing agent after editing some information like name and surname

```
public static Result editResellerSubmit(String email){
    Form<Reseller> editedReseller = sResellerForm.bindFromRequest();
    Optional<Reseller> oldReseller = Reseller.get(email);
    if (!oldReseller.isPresent())
        return badRequest("This reseller does not exist");
    if (editedReseller.hasErrors() ){
        return badRequest(editReseller.render(editedReseller));
    }else{
        Reseller updatedReseller = oldReseller.get();
        try{
            editedReseller.get().encryptPassword();
            editedReseller.get().id = updatedReseller.id;
            JPA.em().merge(editedReseller.get());
            JPA.em().flush();
            flash("success" , Messages.get("ModifiedSuccesfully"));
            return listResellers();
        }catch(PersistenceException e){
            List<ValidationError> list = new ArrayList<>(1);
            list.add(new ValidationError("", e.getMessage() , new ArrayList()));
            editedReseller.errors().put("", list);
            return badRequest(editReseller.render(editedReseller));
        }
    }
}
```

But after i merge, the reference to the reseller is gone, like if the merge, does not actually merge. The problem does not exist obviously if i set manually

Comment: ouch, I really don't follow most of that code. But I see you manually changing an ID property of an entity, that is a huge red flag for me and smells like a design mistake. But I can't know for sure since I don't see that ID property anywhere in your entity code.

Comment: I take a reseller, fill the form with his data, and let the user edit it, then after the submit i reach the editReselleSubmit method. When i reach the try block i got a modified (by the user) version of the reseller that i wish i could merge with the original one, and this can be done only if the 2 objects have the same id, as we can see from the original [example](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/samples/java/computer-database-jpa/app/models/Computer.java#L51) in the update method, merge fail because reseller reference i got is gone, so we are still missing something